# convert a VS 2010 project to 2011 .vcxproj files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

We have an existing code in VS2010 project files and it works perfectly. we are trying to convert  VS2010 project to 2011  .vcxproj  files..

any one have any idea how to convert in a smart way

Comment: Every project I've had gets magically converted when opening the project in VS2012

Comment: The smart way is to not convert.  VS2012 is the first VS version that can open projects created in a previous version of VS without converting them.  It will automatically convert only if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, all I needed to do was open the VS2010 projects in VS2012.

You could take a look at what gets changed in the xml of the .vcxproj file.  I believe it is only a string that changes from v10 to v11

```
<PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
```

EDIT: you could write a batch to mass convert these, or use some sort of XSLT to auto-transform them...